# Fetch_array not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm request a database to get the 5 last mesures of a script, the problem is I can't convert the query into an array which I need to display an Histogram

```
$query=mysql_query('Select Nombre from mesure_actifs order by Date desc limit 5');
$valeurs=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

I get this

[image]

Comment: `mysql_*` Warning
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Did you check that query itself works? Are there any other errors?

Comment: The query works and I'm using php 5

Comment: Any errors `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only fetch one row use mysql_fetch_assoc instead mysql_fetch_array.

For fetching multiple rows Use,

```
    $query=mysql_query('Select Nombre from mesure_actifs order by Date desc limit 5'); 
    while($valeurs=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $var = $valeurs['Nombre'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As php manual on [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) indicates:

> Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

This means that a call to this function fetches a **single** row from the resultset. This means that

```
$valeurs=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

code fetches only the 1st row from your resultset. As the examples on the linked manual page indicate, you need to use a loop to get all data retrieved from your resultset. The user contributed notes below the manual section describe how to create an array out of the results, if you do not know how to create one in a loop.

But you should truly move away from the mysql_*() functions and use mysqli or PDO instead.